# How can I edit the bootup screen in a Fedora ISO?

Tags: boot, fedora, iso-image, desktop-customization

I want to modify a Fedora ISO image so that when I install it, it will use a custom image for the bootup screen and desktop. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the boot screen image and the desktop background image (wallpaper) from the Fedora desktop environment after you have installed Fedora and booted to your desktop. This is easier to do than modifying the Fedora ISO image, and it can be done using GUI applications.

1. Change the background that is shown when the system boots

   If you are using Fedora 20, open the terminal and type:

   ```
   su
   wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Kenzy:/packages/Fedora_20/home:Kenzy:packages.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/home:Kenzy:packages.repo
   yum update
   yum install grub-customizer
   ```

   Open the graphical Grub Customizer application, select the *Appearance settings* tab and change the boot screen background image.

   If you are using Fedora 19, substitute `wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Kenzy:/packages/Fedora_19/home:Kenzy:packages.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/home:Kenzy:packages.repo` for the second command.
2. Change the desktop background

   Open an image with Image Viewer (eog), right-click on it, and select *Set as Desktop Background*. For best results use a desktop background image that has the png format.